# TextInput component suggests

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEGy7.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEGy7.png
I have a TextInput component how can I write content and it suggests the next word that is highlighted as the image
when i enter F and it automatically adds b.com is blacked out

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list with common keywords that you use in your app, something like this:

```
[
   {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "chicken",
   }
   {
       "id": 2,
       "name": "banana",
   }
]
```

Note that ideally you would be getting this data from an API and not manually add it yourself.
Then, make a simple search bar and declare a new variable using useState:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState([])

...

<TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Search food...' onChangeText={handleChange}/>
```

The handleChange function is in charge of setting the new data Filter:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {

        const currentFilter = data.filter((item) => {

            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase())
        })

        setFilter(currentFilter)
    }
```

For displaying the data that you want, you can use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). Just insert the following snippet inside the View in which you want to display your data:

```
{

                filter.length != 0 && (

                    <View>

                        {
                            filter.map((item, key) => {
                                return <Text key={item.id} style={styles.textstyle}>{item.name}</Text>
                            })
                        }

                    </View>
                )

            }
```

Here is the full code:

```
export default function FilteringTest() {

    const [filter, setFilter] = useState([])

    const handleChange = (e) => {

        const currentFilter = data.filter((item) => {

            return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.toLowerCase())
        })

        setFilter(currentFilter)
    }

    return (

        <View style={styles.background}>

            <TextInput style={styles.textinput} placeholder='Search food...' onChangeText={handleChange} />

            {

                filter.length != 0 && (

                    <View>

                        {
                            filter.map((item, key) => {
                                return <Text key={item.id} style={styles.textstyle}>{item.name}</Text>
                            })
                        }

                    </View>
                )

            }

        </View>
    )
}
```

As for highlighting the values, you can simply create a new Text on top of the searchBar that contains the closest match. I suggest you read this article on filtering data in react native: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-filter-component-in-react/

Answer (score 0):

TextInput for IOS - https://snack.expo.dev/JrWw1Zj5Z

TextInput for android - https://snack.expo.dev/piRXBQv6aM

For better view you can disable borders on TextInput or make TextInput  transparent, and set borders and other styles to Text component